# css for p tag inside form

Tags: html, css

I want to leave some space before the p tag.But now I is sticked to the left side.I want to leave 100px before the p tag.
I attached my css and html.There name and email is stricked to the left position.

```css
p {
    margin-left:100px;
}
.outer {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    height: 737px;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button.logout {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.lout {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.log {
    width:60%;
    height: 10%;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0px solid #f9f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:20px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.rest {
    padding:7%;
    height: 580px;
    padding: 10% 7px;
}
.sidemenu {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
hr {
    margin: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 658px;
    border: 0;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
}
.content {
}
.side {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="log">
        <form name="profile" method="post" class="lout">
            <button class="done" name="done">Done</button>
            <button class="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
    </div><!--End of log div -->
        
    <div class="rest">
        <div class="side">
            <div class="sidemenu"></div>
        </div><!--End of side div -->
        
        <hr>
        
        <div class="content">
             <h1>Profile</h1>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>name</p>
            <p>email</p>
        </form>
    </div><!--End of content -->
```

Comment: So what about it is not working. I see you have `margin-left: 100px` there... You do have invalid HTML though..

Comment: P tag has already 100px space from left. if you try the remove margin-left:100px; you can see the diffirence.

Comment: Do you want to indent the paragraph (move it to the right) or do you wish to add vertical space (move it down)? And do you want to apply this to the first or both paragraphs?

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div class="side">` has a `float: left`. But since the div is short and your `<div class="content">` is longer, it wraps around the side div. All you need is a floating for the content as well:

```
.content {
  float: left;
}
```